# Fade in not working correctly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $.supersized({
            //Background image
            slides  :  [ { image : 'images/pendulumWeb.jpg' } ]                 
        });

        $("form#submit").submit(function() {
            // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
            var email = $('#email').attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: "email="+ email,
                    success: function(){
                         $('form#submit').hide(function() {
                            $('div.success').fadeIn();
                        });
                    }
                });
            return false;
            });
        });

</script>
```

```
<div id="contact">
    <form id="submit" method="post">
        <legend>Enter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter InformationEnter Information</legend>
        <div id="submit">
            <input id="email" name="email" value="Email Address" size="20" type="text" />
            <button class="buttonPositive" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="success" style="display: none;">We will email you shortly.</div>    
</div>
```

I am having a hard time figuring out why when I click my submit button why my text after my success (fadeIn) won't appear below the submit button. I am doing a console log of test but it stops going to the console right below `$('form#submit').hide(function()`..Maybe I am missing something simple here? Problem fixed! Thanks Adam

One more thing! My data is not getting to my db..here is my code..I am getting a primary id of 0 but no data.

```
// This is config.php //
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$sql)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $sql);
//

include('config.php');

// CLIENT INFORMATION  
$email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));  

$addClient  = "INSERT INTO clientEmails (Email) VALUES ('$email')";
mysql_query($addClient) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/jwmhv/). While `hide()` should really have a duration before the callback, jQuery appears to duck-type it, and set the duration to its default value for you.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/DKpHM/2/  ...perhaps your Supersized whatchamacallit is interfering?

Comment: I didn't know how the hide function worked guys. It was the duration I was missing :) The fading in of the div works now. My data now needs to be submitted..

Comment: The DB code looks alright. Try setting error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the callback function to `hide()`:

```
$('form#submit').hide();
$('div.success').fadeIn();
```

Also, you have a form and a div with the same id. I suggest you should change one of them, because that might be what was causing your success message not to show.

Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

The [`hide()` function](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) in jQuery takes a function as the second argument. The first argument is the duration of the animation of hiding the element. If you just want to hide the submit button without animation, you don't need to use the callback, just call `hide()` and then `fadeIn()` your new element. If you do want an animation, specify the duration as the first argument.

Comment: It actually will work with just the callback  http://jsfiddle.net/X49Er/  not sure why you'd want to, but apparently you can.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [hide is a duration](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), second argument is the callback:

```
$('form#submit').hide(0, function() {
    $('div.success').fadeIn();
});
```